# What is the distinction between operator and predicate in this presentation?

Tags: logic

Professor Peter Koellner, In a talk entitled '[On the Question of Whether the Mind Can be Mechanized](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VI7Kr2R1sVI)' ([slides](http://yongcheng.whu.edu.cn/webPageContent/event/Peter-slide.pdf)), about Penrose's argument against strong AI, formalizes the concept of absolute provability (i.e. what can be produced by the idealized human mind) as K, and that of truth as T (slide 19). Later (slide 39) Koellner says "...one avoids the paradoxes of K by treating it as an operator and one avoids the paradoxes of T treating it as typed" without elaborating. In response to a question from the audience at [53:15](https://youtu.be/VI7Kr2R1sVI?t=3195), he says "It's an operator for K and a predicate for T. In this context, where truth is typed, you get an inconsistency if you try to treat K as a predicate. There are theorems due to Montague and Gödel himself, Thompson... that show you have to treat K as an operator."

I am hoping to gain some understanding of the differences between treating something as an operator as opposed to as a predicate, and if anyone can point me to something more on what inconsistencies might arise in this case, I would be most grateful.

Comment: The author treats $K$ as a modal operator, like "it is necessary that..." ($\square$).

Comment: $T$ is the intuitive notion of TRUE, as elucidated by Tarski's semantic theory.

Comment: See slides 19-20: $F$ is a formal system (typical of G's Th) and denotes also the collection of theorems of the system: $F \subseteq T$ means that the system is *sound* and the gist of 2nd Incompl.Th is: $\text {Con}(F) \notin F$ (a system $F$ satisfying G's Th assumptions) cannot prove its own consistency). But if $F$ is sound $\text {Con}(F)$ is true, and thus we have a true formula not provable in $F$ that amounts to saying that the provable formulas cannot exhaust the true ones.

Comment: Re $K$, see slide 21: can we read as the collection of formulas (maybe: mathematical facts ?) known by an idealized mind? If so, Claim 2 sounds like: if the idealized mind knows that a formal system $F$ is sound, then there is a known mathematical fact that is not provable in $F$. This seem reasonable: G's proof of the theorem manufacture an arithmetical formula $G$ that is undecidable in $F$ but it is true if we "read" it as meta-mathematical statement.

Comment: See page 27 for the "rules" regarding the "operator" $K$. They can be interpreted as the axioms governing the "ideal Knowability" predicate. Compare with the "Truth predicate" $T$ od [Axiomatic truth theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-axiomatic/).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA WRT the idealized mind: In slide 25, Koellner is skeptical of the " idealized human mind" (and says more about it in the [talk, starting at 42:25](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VI7Kr2R1sVI&t=2547s)), but puts this aside to proceed with idealizing assumptions that are as favorable as he feels is possible to his opponents.

Comment: And compare with the [Provability predicate](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-provability/) $\text {Prov}$ (or: $\text {Bew}$) of formalized G's Theorem.

Comment: The paradox of knowing is the famous [logical omniscience problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modal_logic#Problems_with_the_possible_world_model_and_modal_model_of_knowledge) in epistemology so we can resolve this by using non-normal modal logic operator K to treat knowledge as justified true belief (but even with this there're still disputes in philosophy like the soundness of epistemic closure property). Truth predicate T originated from Tarski's semantic theory of truth expressed  in a metalanguage which belongs to the major correspondence theory of truth in philosophical.

Comment: A key feature of truth predicate T is it predicates sentence symbols (not objects) thus is a second order theory deciding primitive truth in possibly stratified metalanguages and it's extensional, while modal operator K is intensional thus its truth result may not only depend on the truth of its proposition content...